# Strange grouping of colors in syntax highlighting for Perl and XML

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I have just posted a question related to Perl including some XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38011709/1603480

I was wondering why the the syntax highlighting was strange in the `if` block:

[image: Strange grouping of red]

Any idea??

Comment: The language hint needs to be separated by a line from the above text - I have made that edit and you will see the XML fragment is highlighted correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Oded: I have removed the second part.

Comment: the obligatory [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)